# Django Rest Framework module drf-chunked-upload - upload chunk does not work

Tags: python, django, file-upload, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to send large files in chunks using Django Rest Framework module [drf-chunked-upload](https://github.com/jkeifer/drf-chunked-upload).

But following Typical Usage section and trying a variety of ways the past two days I can't find a way to do that.

1. The first thing that I did was to make the `ChunkedUpload` model concrete to use it in my project and then, make and run migration associated with that.
2. After that I set the `url` to make the requests for in `urls.py`:

   ```
   url(r'^uploadchunks/$', ChunkedUploadView.as_view())
   ```
3. Now, I can make the request to the API following the Typical Usage section in Github project home page, item 1:

> An initial PUT request is sent to the url linked to ChunkedUploadView
>   (or any subclass) with the first chunk of the file. The name of the
>   chunk file can be overriden in the view (class attribute field_name)

4. Using [httpie](http://httpie.org) to make the request I run (the whole file has 32095676 bytes and I'm sendint 10000000 at time):

   ```
   http -a <username>:<password> -f PUT http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploadchunks/ file@~/<first_filechunk> filename='file' 'Content-Range: bytes 0-10000000/32095676'
   ```

After that I get the error:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'chunkedupload-detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': UUID('a6b2f690-1653-4821-bcfd-b0edce60948a')}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

although the item 2 of Typical Usage section says that we've supposed to receive a response:

> In return, the server will respond with the url of the upload, the
>   current offset, and when the upload will expire (expires). Example:
>
> ```
> {
>     "url": "https://your-host/<path_to_view>/5230ec1f59d1485d9d7974b853802e31",
>     "offset": 10000,
>     "expires": "2013-07-18T17:56:22.186Z" 
> }
> ```

I've been wondering if the error message above was referring to a missing View (ChunkedUploadDetailView?), so I created that view with basic code:

```
class ChunkedUploadDetailView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = ChunkedUpload.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ChunkedUploadSerializer
```

with url conf

```
url(r'^uploadchuncks/(?P<pk>.*)/$', views.ChunkedUploadDetailView,
        name='chunkedupload-detail')
```

Now, I can send the first file chunk, and I receive the response:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, PUT, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Fri, 03 Mar 2017 19:20:46 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.0+
Vary: Accept, Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

{
    "completed_at": null,
    "created_at": "2017-03-03T19:20:46.502345Z",
    "file": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploadchunks/chunked_uploads/2017/03/03/1c469fab-1d0c-4c14-84b3-0d51aa36c8f2.part",
    "filename": "file0",
    "id": "1c469fab-1d0c-4c14-84b3-0d51aa36c8f2",
    "offset": 10000000,
    "status": 1,
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploadchuncks/1c469fab-1d0c-4c14-84b3-0d51aa36c8f2/",
    "user": 2
}
```

from `httpie`.

So, I thought I was on the right way, but now when I follow the third item of Typical Usage section:

> Repeatedly PUT subsequent chunks to the url returned from the server.
>   Example:
>
> # PUT to
>   https://your-host//5230ec1f59d1485d9d7974b853802e31
>
> {
>       "my_file": file }

and I run:

```
http -a indc:indc@indc -f PUT http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploadchunks/1c469fab-1d0c-4c14-84b3-0d51aa36c8f2/ file@~/Downloads/<second_filechunk> filename='file' 'Content-Range: bytes 10000000-20000000/32095676'
```

to send the second file chunk I get shell error:

```
http: error: ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe')) while doing PUT request to URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploadchunks/1c469fab-1d0c-4c14-84b3-0d51aa36c8f2/
```

and, in django virtual server:

```
Not Found: /uploadchunks/1c469fab-1d0c-4c14-84b3-0d51aa36c8f2/
[03/Mar/2017 16:29:22] "PUT /uploadchunks/1c469fab-1d0c-4c14-84b3-0d51aa36c8f2/ HTTP/1.1" 404 4788
```

what it seems the module can't find the model instance associated with
`pk=1c469fab-1d0c-4c14-84b3-0d51aa36c8f2`.

So I'm stucked here for two days.

As I'm a new python/django developer, I can't find until now a way to solve the problem. It seems to me that there are pieces that I have to implement, but I don't know why.

If anyone already used drf-chunked-upload, and know what I'm missing, I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

In the url I see you spell 'uploadchunks' in some places, and 'uploadchuncks' in others. That could be the cause.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27240099)

Comment: @GertArnold Too harsh. There is an answer in here.

Comment: I'm viewing this my question only now and maybe you are right @peter. I'm not on the project related to that now. So I can't tell you for sure by now. Anyway, thanks for noticing that.